# How can I make a link to a git changeset in Trac when there is more than one repository and neither one is default?

Tags: git, hyperlink, trac, changeset

While working with just one associated repository, I was quite used to reference changesets in my Trac tickets using the *changeset* keyword and the commit's SHA1 hash like this:

```
[changeset:af54b6d]
```

which would give me an hyperlink to the corresponding changeset.

Now I'm working on a project where the same Trac environment (version 0.12) has multiple git repositories associated with it and no one is - and shouldn't be - the default, so the above syntax doesn't work anymore.

Can anyone please help me figuring out how to refer to a changeset in a specific repository?

Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your repository is named `repo`, you can link to the changeset with `[changeset:af54b6d/repo]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using subversion, but asuming git changeset links work the sam way, you should use `repo:changeset:af54b6d`, where you must define `repo` in the `[intertrac]` section of the `trac.ini`. See also [InterTrac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/InterTrac)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wimmel, this intertrac facility will really help referring to elements in other projects, which is something I do sometimes too. The syntax `repo:changeset:af54b6d` though would point to the Trac environment *repo*, not to the version control repository, which belongs to the same Trac environment I'm working at - I suppose that intertrac wouldn't be needed in this case.